# Open link within PDF in a new browser window (PDFsharp using silverPDF.dll)

Tags: pdfsharp

In a Silverlight web application I have created PDF using PDFsharp’s silverPDF.dll. Within that PDF I have added some active links. I want links within PDF on click it opens new browser window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In PDFsharp you add web links using

```
PdfPage.AddWebLink Method
```

You cannot specify the target.